# Will Drupal 8 Twig have template inheritance like Drupal 7?

Tags: 8, theming

Drupal 7 you can style down to the fields on the page will we have this type of control with twig? I have reviewed a lot of documents about twig and didn't see anything that lets you have that same inheritance as the Drupal 7 template engine. If this is not built in to twig, is Drupal 8 going to be building it in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you might be confusing inheritance with granularity. Twig actually does have the concept of template inheritance (see [extends](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html)), while Drupal 7's theme engine doesn't.

The short answer is yes, you can expect the same from Drupal 8 as you did from Drupal 7. Specifically for fields, the example in the docs for [field.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!templates!field.html.twig/8) will give you some insight:

> For example, for a field named 'body' displayed on the 'article' content type, any of the following templates will override this default implementation. The first of these templates that exists is used:
>
> field--node--field-foo--article.html.twig
>
> field--node--field-foo.html.twig
>
> field--node--article.html.twig
>
> field--field-foo.html.twig
>
> field--text-with-summary.html.twig
>
> field.html.twig

These can be altered/added to using [`hook_theme_suggestions_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_alter/8), or the more specific [`hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8).

Comment: There currently seems to be an open issue in D8.5 that field templates by content type don't get picked up by default: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2265251